# Error when calling SpalshScreen inside the main.dart using Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my app, I have 3 values I need to get each time someone opens the app. So I write them in the intestate inside the splash screen because it is the first screen in the app.
Now, I am having a problem when calling the SplashScreen from main.dart.

the output is :

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: call()
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:28
```

(this error occurs each 1 second as I set the Timer to navigate to MyHomePage)

this is my `main.dart`

```
import 'package:basic_project/providers/language_provider.dart';
import 'package:basic_project/providers/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:basic_project/screens/general_setting.dart';
import 'package:basic_project/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:basic_project/screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:basic_project/widgets/app_drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'screens/setting_screen.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
      create: (ctx) => ThemeProvider(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<LanguageProvider>(
      create: (ctx) => LanguageProvider(),
    )
  ], child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Basic App',
        themeMode: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).tm,

        home: SplashScreen());   // here I am calling SplashScreen as a home Screen to get data from shareprefrences
  }
}
```

and this is my `SplashScreen.dart`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:basic_project/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/language_provider.dart';
import '../providers/theme_provider.dart';
import '../shared/constants.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState()  {
    Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false).getThemeMode();
    Provider.of<LanguageProvider>(context, listen: false).getLanguage();
    Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false).getThemeColors();

    super.initState();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 1),
        () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage())));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).primaryColor,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 90,
                  width: 90,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/flutter.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

update: problem solved, it was a syntax error.
I updated the code.